# Why Selenium using Maven has build errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am doing Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse.

In my 1st project I get WebDriver library from downloading 'selenium-java-2.45.0.zip', and add them by 'Java Build Path' -> 'Libraries' -> 'add External JARs' in Eclipse.

Then I write my test scripts for the project, everything runs fine.

In my 2nd project I try to manage WebDriver library by Maven. In my project POM.xml file, I have the following lines:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

exactly following the instructions from Seleniumhq website.

However this time although the project compiles fine, when I try to 'maven test' to run some test script, following build errors show up

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Optional
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.loadCustomExtension(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.addWebDriverExtensionIfNeeded(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at test.java.NewTest.beforeMethod(NewTest.java:39)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Optional
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 45 more
```

at code line:

```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //this line
        ...
    }
```

Seems some library is missing. What could be the problem? Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: @Jens thanks for your reply, will try it when return home. any reason for this fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `guava-<version>.jar` jar in you classpath. please add it to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```